# Can i place a manually extracted war in tomcat instead of deployOnStartup=true. Is it proper to have already extracted war files in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I added  deployOnStartup="true" in the tomcat server.xml. But it is recommended to have deployOnStartup="false" due to security issue as keeping it true allows malicious or untested applications to be deployed and so it should be disabled.
What is the issue with keeping the extracted war files in the webapps directly, without having to extract each time.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to your statement _"But it is recommended to have deployOnStartup="false" "_? On the other hand `deployOnStartup` does not mean that only WARs will be deployed.

Comment: This recommendation comes from CIS Apache Tomcat Benchmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `deployOnStartup` does. There are 4 ways to add a web application to Tomcat:

1. Configure a `<Context>` element inside a `<Host>` element in `conf/server.xml`. Any change to the `<Context>` element will require a server restart,
2. Add an `<application-name>.xml` file to the host's *configBase* directory (`conf/Catalina/<host-name>`),
3. Add a WAR file to the host's *appBase* directory (usually `webapps`),
4. Add a directory to the host's *appBase* directory.

There is no difference between 3 and 4.

If you set `deployOnStartup="false"` **and** `autoDeploy="false"`, web applications defined using 2, 3 and 4 will **not** be deployed. You'll need to manually deploy them through JMX or Tomcat Manager after each server restart. If you leave `autoDeploy="true"` (default value), web applications from points 2, 3 and 4 will not be deployed at startup, but a few seconds later, when Tomcat scans for changes in the applications.

From a security perspective `deployOnStartup="false"` is an extreme solution, as it forces you to define everything inside `server.xml`. You can obtain a similar effect by:

- making the entire `conf` directory writable by the administrator only and readable by the system user running Tomcat,
- making the `webapps` directory writable by the administrator and Tomcat user only. If you make it writable by the administrator only, you'll need to set `unpackWARs="false"` and you will not be able to deploy new WARs using Tomcat Manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Understood the use of deployOnStartup="false". Actually according to CIS_Apache_Tomcat_8_Benchmark section 9.3, it is recommended to disable auto deployment of applications in tomcat as this could allow malicious or untested applications to be deployed. So we thought of manually deploying the application instead of tomcat having to deploy the war.

Comment: Remark: unpacking a WAR archive into a directory is not the same thing as _deploying_ it, even if it should speed up the application. Deploying means adding to Tomcat's configuration and since you'll have `deployOnStartup="false"` you'll need to define everything in `server.xml` (and restarting everything after each change).

Comment: "If deployOnStartup="false" need to define everything" -> can you also inform one example of what we have to do define additional in server.xml incase of false value.