# I'm unable to create a custom tag in tomcat8 in ubuntu OS without unsing any IDE

Tags: ubuntu, jsp, jstl, tomcat8, custom-tag

I have to create custom tags to complete my project without using any IDE on ubuntu(Linux) but I'm repeteadly getting an error message.

To create custom tag I've made two files tagfileone.tag and tagfileonetest.jsp and their locations are as:
for tagfileonetest.jsp:    /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/Trying_Tag
for tagfileone.tag:        /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/Trying_Tag/WEB-INF/tag

here Trying_Tag is the name of directory where my web application is.

But I repeteadly get an error on browser while running which says:

```
Trying_Tag/tagfileonetest.jsp (line: 13, column: 28) No tag "tagfileone" defined in tag library imported with prefix "tf"
```

I'm adding snapshots for more clearance.
If someone can help I'll be really grateful.......

[Path to JSP File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUoGi.png)

[Path to Tag file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUM86.png)

[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUoGi.png)

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUM86.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1bZe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the default Ubuntu configuration Tomcat automatically deploys all directories in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`. You didn't deploy an application `Trying_Tag`, but only an application `ROOT` with a folder `Trying_Tag`. Therefore your JSP is looking in the folder `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/tags` for the tag files and does not find any.

Move the `Trying_Tag` folder to `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps` and everything should work fine.

**Remark**: the URLs will remain the same, because a web application called `ROOT` has an empty context path, so `ROOT/foo/bar.jsp` will be accessible with an empty context path and `/foo/bar.jsp` as path info (the concatenation is `/foo/bar.jsp`), while `foo/bar.jsp` will have a context path of `/foo` and a path info `/bar.jsp`, which results in the same URL.

Comment: Thanks Sir, it solved my problem. Could you recommend me some reading to understand all this. I mean all this ubuntu config. and Tomcat due to which i couldn't solve my problem...

Comment: How Tomcat deploys applications you can read in [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup) or, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345939/11748454). In Ubuntu `/var/lib/tomcat8` is `CATALINA_BASE`, but many directories are actually symbolic links to comply with [FHS](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard).